# How to move tableView up inorder to popUp a view from bottom So that it is not on top of table in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a tableView.It exists from half portion of iPhone screen to bottom.If I click any cell a
    popup comes up from bottom. When it appears on the screen table should move up,So that popup does 
    not overlap on tableView.

```
Can anyone suggest How to do this.
Thanks in Advance.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set,

```
CGPoint _contentOffset = CGPointMake(tableView.contentOffset.x, aNegativeYValue);
tableView.contentOffset = _contentOffset;
```

If you want it animated, use,

```
CGPoint _contentOffset = CGPointMake(tableView.contentOffset.x, aNegativeYValue);
[tableView setContentOffset:_contentOffset animated:YES];
```

You can also use table view's [scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/scrollToRowAtIndexPath%3aatScrollPosition%3aanimated%3a) method.

Comment: When I am using this it showing an error as "Called Object is not a function".

Comment: @Monish Kumar, Sorry there is a mistake in my answer. I'll edit now :-)

Comment: @Monish Kumar, You can also use scrollToRowAtIndexPath method, See my updated answer

Comment: Hey can u pls post the method in detail

Comment: Is it a delegate method or we have to call that method.

Comment: @Monish Kumar, Yeah. Its a instance method. You have call it directly.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to embed your tableView (and your other views, since you apparently have more than one view on screen) in a `UIScrollView`.

Then when you present the popup window on screen, calculate an offset to scroll to by getting your popup window's size, 
then slide up the tableView using `[scrollView setContentOffset:MyOffset animated:YES]`.